# Select Permission was denied on the column for a user

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a user which is added to a role xyz and this role has been assigned some permissions like data read/write, execute etc on a database.

While executing a select query on a column of a table it displays an error

> The select permission was denied on the column ...

I could see while taking the properties of the table that that role has been granted as select to all the columns in that table.

Can anyone point me to what I'm missing?

Comment: Is that a table or a view? It might be a view selecting a subset of columns from the underlying table.

Comment: @Vikdor: It is definitely a column under dbo.table

Comment: DENY trumps GRANT. Look in sys.database_permissions for any DENY permissions. major_id = object_id of the table, minor_id = column_id. But look for any DENY permissions; they assert themselves in non-obvious ways sometimes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found out the solution. This specific user was added to another role in which "Deny" permissions was set against these tables. Removing that permission solved my issue...